# How to use JS Fiddle for rending React select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsfiddle, react-select

I want to render third party library react-select in JS Fiddle. I have added libraries in jsfiddle but not sure how to use Select component from react-select. I am getting "Error Select is not defined".

https://jsfiddle.net/7nydx09p/1/

```
const App = () => {

    return <div> Test
  <Select />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic as it is not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look here : https://jsfiddle.net/zh4593oL/1/

look here for the issue : https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4120

html

```
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="module">
  import Select from 'https://cdn.pika.dev/react-select@^3.1.0';
  window.Select = Select;
</script>
```

js

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

const App = () => {

    return <div> <Select options={options} />  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I want to add react-select component which is third party library. How to render in jsfiddle

Comment: @Trinu i have updated the jsfiddle accordingly

Comment: Awesome Thanks a lot. I have been searching from the morning for this. Great Help.